How to change from Greek keyboard layout in terminal / command line (Ubuntu 24.04)
My Ubuntu 24.04 installation is currently unstable and I want to carry out repairs in safe mode (command line). However, I'm unable to execute any commands because the terminal is stuck in Greek keyboard layout.
I have booted into removable media in order to fix it by changing xkbvariant (/etc/default/keyboard), but the setting in xkbvariant was already correct.
I assume there's another file that's setting the keyboard, but I have no idea what it might be.
